# Magento 2: How to create a customer custom attribute?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-attribute

What are steps to create a custom attribute for Customer entity in Magento 2?

Comment: ADDING AN ATTRIBUTE PROGRAMMATICALLY IN MAGENTO 2 article https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-attribute-programatically-magento2/ it step by step

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the article [Magento 2: How to make customer attribute?](http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html) describe it step by step.

The main part is `DataInstall::install` method below:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, '{attributeCode}', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => '{attributeLabel}',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magento_username')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
```

Comment: What is the benefit of injecting `CustomerSetupFactory` instead of directly injecting `CustomerSetup`? Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @Vinai,  Looks looks customerSetup class expects ModuleDataSetupInterface in constructor but this class is argument of install method.

Comment: Since `ModuleDataSetupInterface` has no state that is specific to the setup class, wouldn't it be better to let the ObjectManager be responsible for creating the instance dependencies then? That way the `CustomerSetup` client would be less coupled to the implementation. As far as I can see.

Comment: Removing the module doesn't remove the attribute, how should it be removed then ?

Comment: How can we add more than one fieds or attributes?

Comment: I want to create customer attribute using my custom module's helper.is there a way to do this without install script?

Comment: "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216191/shipping-address-custom-attribute-value-not-set-in-database-in-magento2-2" an idea about it?

Comment: @KAndy, I used the above code, my customer attribute not getting created. Do I need to change the module version?

Answer (score 3):

Create Data Patch file AddMobileCustomerAttribute.php in \Setup\Patch\Data

```
<?php
 /**
  * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace vendor\CustomerAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddMobileCustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        
        /** @var $attributeSet Set */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'mobile',
            [
                'label' => 'secondary mobile',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
        
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile');
        $attribute->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId
        
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
        
        ];
    }
}
```

Add this file to your module.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2):

In your module, implement this file below that'll create a new **Customer entity**.

**Test\CustomAttribute\Setup\InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace test\CustomAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' =>999,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],//you can use other forms also ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: not working....

Comment: This worked for me on Magneto 2.3 http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer

Comment: @Rafael Corrêa Gomes is it possible to create multiple attributes using this method? How?

Comment: @ZUBU you just need to add a new $customerSetup->addAttribute next of the first one, you can search for ->addAttribute into the core also to see references.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace XYZ\AdminViewLink\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'isAdmin',
            [
                'type'         => 'boolean',
                'label'        => 'isAdmin',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'isAdmin');

        // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']

        );
        $sampleAttribute->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) 
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', [
                'label' => 'Label',
                'system' => 0,
                'position' => 720,
                'sort_order' => 720,
                'visible' => true,
                'note' => '',
                'type' => 'int',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'backend' => \Custom\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend\DoWHatEver::class,
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $this->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute');
        $attribute->addData([
                'is_user_defined' => 1,
                'is_required' => 0,
                'default_value' => 0,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
            ])->save();
    }
    
    public function getEavConfig() 
    {
        return $this->eavConfig;
    }
}
```