# How to save customer attribute value in custom script in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer-attribute, script, save

How to save customer attribute value in custom script in Magento 2.

The prerequisite is to add first your new attribute programatically.

To do add a customer attribute please review these:

- [Magento2 create a customer custom attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/magento2-create-a-customer-custom-attribute)
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1238#issuecomment-105034397

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how it can be done with customer save method:

```
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory */
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer */
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer $customerData */

$customer = $customerFactory->create()
$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('my_attr_code', $val);
$customer->updateData($customerData);
$customer->save();
```

And this is how it can be done updating only one attribute value:

```
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory */
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer */
$customer = $customerFactory->create();
//$customer->setId($customerId); // This seem redundant
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer $customerData */
// interface \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
$customerData->setId($customerId);

$customerData->setCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute', $value);

$customer->updateData($customerData);

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer $customerResource */
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory $customerResourceFactory */
$customerResource = $customerResourceFactory->create();

if ($value != "") {
    $customerResource->saveAttribute($customer, 'my_custom_attribute');
}
```

Comment: I have followed the same, but its not saving. could you please help me.

Comment: Dunno why but i got my script working with this approach, whereas using $customer->setCustomAttribute('attr','val') was working only on  the first entry I was saving. in my dev environment it was working also the other way, but not in my stage environment... really strange. Any clue?

Comment: I saw this kind of behaviour too. I don't recall if there were products or customers. And Magento 2 was in  a kind of infinite loop. The debug trace had Gbs.

Comment: It may not be your case, but my workaround to the save issue that took too long, was to use object manager instead of injecting classes in constructor.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191947/set-value-to-created-customer-custom-attribute-in-magento-2#233445 it working without effecting customer session

Comment: Working for a single custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quite nice solution for this :

```
protected $customerRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

...

public function updateCustomerAttribute($customerId, $attributeCode, $value) {
    $customerData = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    $customerData->setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $value);
    $this->customerRepository->save($customerData);
}
```