# Magento 2 - i want get customer by id and set custom attribute to customer

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-attribute

I am working on extension and need to set customer custom attribute value.
I tried the following code, but it's not working , can you please help me with this.

```
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
$customer->setId($observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getId());
$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('mobilenumber','123465798');
$customer->updateData($customerData);
$customer->save();
```

Comment: Try this:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106407/how-to-save-customer-attribute-value-in-custom-script-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code,

```
//declare repository
    protected $repository;

//inside your function

  $this->repository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface');

  $customerId = 5; //get customer id

  $address = $this->repository->getById($customerId);

  $customerData = $address;
  // change phone #
  $customerData->setMobilenumber('12345678');
  $customerDataSave = $this->repository->save($customerData);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, full solution not work for me, but i can get idea from your code, so Thank you so much.

Comment: @bharatdesai please post the solution as answer