# Set value to created customer custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes

I have created custom attribute for customer using below code.

setup/installData.php

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

const LEGALITY_DOCUMENT_1 = 'user_legality_document_1';
protected $customerSetupFactory;
private $attributeSetFactory;


public function __construct(
CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
) {

    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
    $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, self::LEGALITY_DOCUMENT_1, [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Legal Document',
        'input' => 'image',
        "source" => '',
        'required' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 210,
        'position' => 210,
        'system' => false,
    ]);

    $document = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, self::LEGALITY_DOCUMENT_1)
            ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'],
    ]);

    $document->save();
    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

}

Now i want to set value to this attribute pragmatically.

How can i do achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check below code is working great for me. Tested with Magento 2.3.3

```
        $avatar = $this->request->getParam('avatar');
         // \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerModel,
            $customerNew = $this->customerModel->load($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
            $customerData = $customerNew->getDataModel();
            $customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_avatar',$customerAvatar);
            $customerNew->updateData($customerData);
            // \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
            $customerResource = $this->customerResourceFactory->create();
            $customerResource->saveAttribute($customerNew, 'customer_avatar');
```

Comment: It's working.. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 11):

This may help for you to save the custom attribute.

```
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
) {
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $customerId = 2; // Corresponding customer id
    $customer = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerId)->getDataModel();
    $customer->setCustomAttribute('custom_attribute_name', 'value');
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. but this won't work. You are saving attribute with type text, i have image type and need to save from external URL.

Comment: This code not working in magento 2.2.3, please suggest if you have any alternate solution please share as I want to save custom customer address attribute value programmatically.

Comment: this is working perfect for custom attribute with text type. thanks @sabarivenkatesankrish

Comment: @SanjayVadadoriya, its not worked for me even i the type is text

Comment: this worked great! and using the repository to save the model is the correct way of doing this in Magento2

Comment: @PurushotamSharma this code will save customer attribute, not an address attribute. An address is a separate entity type from customer.

This here should work: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/205265/44585 for saving custom address attributes.

Comment: Loading the object directly from the factory is deprecated since Magento 2.3. The correct way is to use Service Contract:
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);

Answer (score 5):

To save custom customer attribute

Code Tested in Magento v2.2.1 and it working.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory as CustomerResourceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

/**
 * Class Index
 */
class Index extends Action
{
    const CUSTOM_CUSTOMER_ATTR = 'xyz';
    /**
     * @var CustomerResourceFactory
     */
    protected $customerResourceFactory;
    /**
     * @var Customer
     */
    protected $customerModel;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSession
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CustomerResourceFactory $customerResourceFactory
     * @param Customer $customerModel
     * @param CustomerSession $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CustomerResourceFactory $customerResourceFactory,
        Customer $customerModel,
        CustomerSession $customerSession
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerResourceFactory = $customerResourceFactory;
        $this->customerModel = $customerModel;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /* ********* Start : Important area :  to save custom customer attribute value without losing session on refresh *********** */

        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customAttributeValue = $this->getRequest()->getParam('custom_attribute'); // it just an example to pull value

            $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

            $customerNew = $this->customerModel->load($customerId);
            $customerData = $customerNew->getDataModel();
            $customerData->setCustomAttribute(self::CUSTOM_CUSTOMER_ATTR, $customAttributeValue);
            $customerNew->updateData($customerData);

            $customerResource = $this->customerResourceFactory->create();
            $customerResource->saveAttribute($customerNew, self::CUSTOM_CUSTOMER_ATTR);

            /* ********* End: Important area :  to save custom customer attribute value without losing session on refresh *********** */

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You are successfully save the data!!'));
        }
        return $this->_redirect('route/controller/action'); // it just an example for return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Developer Webile, Your code in question is invalid (few uses missed and other things).
I added missing things. Here is Working code.
P.S. Changed const name for better understanding/reading.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory as CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    const NEW_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'new_attribute_name';
    protected $customerSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;


    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    )
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, self::NEW_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Comment for new field',
            'input' => 'image',
            "source" => '',
            'required' => false,
            'default' => '0',
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 210,
            'position' => 210,
        ]);

        $document = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, self::NEW_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'],
            ]);

        $document->save();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Load your customer and try this:

```
$customer->setData('your_option_name', $yourOptionValue);

$customer->save();
```

Comment: This isn't working alreay tried below.                                                    $customer->setMedicalReport($medicalReport);

Cause i am getting URL from which i need to save image/pdf.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Pranav\CustomerAttribute\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
class CustomerAttributeUpdate 
{
/**
 * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
 */
private $customerRepository;
/**
 * @var CustomerFactory
 */
private $customerFactory;

/**
 * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    CustomerFactory $customerFactory
) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}
public function execute($customer): string
{
   
        $customerId = $customer->getEcommId();
        $customerAdditional = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
//if you need to get customer custom attribute 

        $registrationDate = $customerAdditional->getRegistrationDate();
        $renewalDate = $customerAdditional->getRenewalDate();
        $expiryDate = $customerAdditional->getExpiryDate();
        $customerInterface->setCustomAttribute('registration_datetime', $registrationDate);
        $customerInterface->setCustomAttribute('renewal_date', $renewalDate);
        $customerInterface->setCustomAttribute('expiry_date', $expiryDate);
        $this->customerRepository->save($customerInterface);        
}
```