# magento2 create customer attribute

Tags: magento2, attribute-set, customer-attribute

Anyone Can help me, I want to add customer Attribute and i have put my code as below.I have installed it, not getting any error but noting happened.

**Customer/Attrib/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Customer\Attrib\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;



/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_measurements', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Mymeasurements',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_measurements')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['customer_address_edit'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
}
```

**Customer/Attrib/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Customer_Attrib',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Customer/Attrib/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Customer_Attrib"  setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>           
            <module name="Customer_Attrib"/>  
        </sequence>   
   </module>
</config>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Refer this link to fulfill your requirement : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/magento2-create-a-customer-custom-attribute

Comment: How to add more than one attributes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make below change in module.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Customer_Attrib"  setup_version="1.0.0">
       <sequence>           
            <!--<module name="Customer_Attrib"/>-->
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>   
   </module>
</config>
```

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Customer\Attrib\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();


        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_measurements', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Mymeasurements',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_measurements')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['customer_address_edit',customer_form],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();



    }
}
```

Now run commands,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
rm -rf  pub/static/frontend/
rm -rf var/cache/rm -rf var/page_cache/
rm -rf var/generation/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Now Login to amdin your attribute will be displayed in customer section as screen shot.**

[image]

[UPDATE]
If still you don't get it, please make sure to add below code to `app/code/<vendor>/<module>/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="my_measurements" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> After this run commands as above.

Comment: It's working fine. Thank you for your help @RJ07. It's display on admin side but i want that on customer side in profile edit mode.

Comment: how would we add multiple attributes to a user instead of just one? Can we repeat the code from addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY,...  to $attribute->save();  ?

Comment: How to add more than one attributes?

Comment: But it is not rendering on checkout page.

Comment: it's working fine but it's value not save while save data and also this attribute not working in frontend while get it's value like $block->getMymeasurements();

Answer (score 0):

Your module xml should be:

**Customer/Attrib/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Customer_Attrib"  setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>           
            <!--<module name="Customer_Attrib"/>-->
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>   
   </module>
</config>
```

**Customer/Attrib/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
        $setup->startSetup();

        //Your add attribute code here

        $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Remember to run setup upgrade command.

Comment: Nope Still not working

Comment: Try to remove your module in `setup_module` table. Try to run setup upgrade command again.

Comment: I can't see my module in `setup_module` table

Comment: Try to clear your Magento Cache and run setup upgrade command again.

Answer (score 0):

We do have an option to create a customer attribute/s with the magento2 silk software tool which is very easy. please follow the steps below might be useful.

Please find the screenshot:

Step1: Create a module with the selection of customer attribute from using the module creator tool.

[image: Magento 2 silk software tool]

Step 2: Download the zip and install it in your magento2 using module installed steps

Step3: Clear flush cache and page cache and login into your admin check it.

**Output:**

[image: admin end customers section]