# Magento 2 : How to Add address attribute in billing address form and convert that value in order address

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address, address

**I want to create address attribute and convert that attribute to order address.**

1. I want to add address attribute in billing and shipping address of customer.
2. Also want to display this attribute everywhere like in customer address (add/edit).
3. Also want to save this value in quote and convert to order address address (billing/shipping).
4. Show this attribute in shipping / billing form on checkout.

How we can achieve this all functionality ?

Comment: R u using CE or EE?

Comment: @AnkitShah I am using CE (Magento 2.1).

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/magento2-create-a-customer-custom-attribute I'm using https://codecanyon.net/item/magento-2-ce-customer-attribute-system/16399784 for ease. it will help long term & cheapest