# How to add a custom field to the frontend customer registration form in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to add following below fields to the fronted customer registration form.

- 1.company
- 2.Address
- 3.street
- 4.city
- 5.state
- 6.country
- 7.zip code
- 8.phone no
- 9.federal tax id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento2 create a customer custom attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/magento2-create-a-customer-custom-attribute)

Comment: i  have add fields only frontend page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show address fields in registration form, Create the `customer_account_create.xml` file on the path `app/design/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Customer/layout` and add the below code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields">
            <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```